# Meaning of phrase about emotion of disappointment

Tags: idioms

This is a paragraph from an [article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/erikaboissiere/2018/11/07/3-ways-to-keep-resentment-from-ruining-your-career/amp/%3Famp_js_v=0.1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%253D#ampf=). Can anyone explain the meaning of bold fonted part? It seems for me coming out of nowhere.

*You hear your manager say, “Sorry, you won’t be getting a promotion this year. We’ll aim for next year.” The knee-jerk reaction is anger. And for many, the news can also **send their finger scrambling for the eject button**. Your inner voice asks, “Why stay at a job where I’m not appreciated?” It’s understandable; we all get it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fighter jet airplane, there is a button that ejects the pilot if the plane is hit. It is a way for the pilot to get out of the plane if things are going very bad.

This is the metaphor.  If things are going badly at your company, if you don't get a promotion you might feel angry and you might want to get out of the company as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you! I now can relate this phrase with the context.